# Concurrent Programming in Java

Tags: java

Is the lock retained by the thread when context switch occur.
When we invoke a wait() the locks are given up by thread, what happens when theres a context switch.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, locks are retained during a context switch. In fact, that's the whole point of a lock.

When a thread calls `wait` it relinquishes the lock. When wait returns the lock is re-obtained, so you can guarantee that when control returns to your thread it holds all the locks you expect.

Comment: +1, though with parallel processors lock has the added responsibility of supporting mutual exclusion across parallel processes/threads.  i.e. context switching isn't a requirement for parallelization.  Either way "context switching" isn't a very Java-oriented concept.  Nothing about Java threading mandates that context switching occur.

Answer (score 1):

The thread that invoked `wait()` gets suspended until some other thread invokes `notify*()` on the object. At that point, when another context switch occurs, the `wait()` call will return and the waiting thread will immediately try to re-acquire the lock before proceeding further.